# Android Java SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

можете подсказать как правильно сохранить и загрузить одну переменную ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Получение экземпляра SharedPreferences

```java
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

#### Сохранение значения строки value по ключу key

```java
preferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
```

#### Считывание строки по ключу

```java
String str = preferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
```